# numbers не наследует методы, которые есть в прототипе Collection

Tags: javascript

```
function Collection() {
    return {
        ar: []
    }
}

var numbers = new Collection();

console.log(numbers.values());
```

Выводит "Uncaught TypeError: numbers.values is not a function" хотя есть такой метод - Collection.prototype.values
Как сделать чтобы объект numbers мог использовать методы Collection.prototype ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var numbers1 = new Map();
var numbers2 = new Set();
var numbers3 = new Array();

console.log(numbers1.values(), numbers2.values(), numbers3.values());
```

---

```js
function Collection() {
    this.ar = [1,2,3];
}

var numbers = new Collection();

console.log(numbers.ar.values().next());
```

Answer (score 1):

В случае, если конструктор возвращает не примитивный объект, вернется именно этот результат, а не создаваемый объект.

Таким образом в примере в вопросе в `numbers` лежит простой объект

```
{
    ar: []
}
```

Который никак не связан с `Collection` и `Collection.prototype`

Comment: Надо было просто вот так мне сделать: function Collection() {
   
        this.ar = []
    
}